# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

Hey Members i am new to C# Language and Visual Studio Platform  recently i am learning how to connect access Database with visual Studio and first time with same code i have connected with database but after some time when i compiled again then there is error given in Title.
why this is happening ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Clinic_Management_System
{
    public partial class Login : Form
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
                connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users
                \Hassan Gillani\Documents\Clinic Management System.accdb;  Persist Security Info = False; ";
                connection.Open();
                label1.Text = "Connected to Clinic Management System Database";
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Error " + exp);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

please visit given like to view screen short 
http://s33.postimg.org/5ltm4dtnj/Error.png

Comment: Make sure your file path is correct, the exception is "not a valid file name"

Comment: Yeah, check if you shouldn't escape the filepath, as it has spaces in the filename

Comment: i verified again the path is okay 
i have given the path by right clicking on file and go properties then security and then copy whole path given in object name field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the verbatim character (@) and splitting your path in the middle in not a good idea.
Spaces counts in paths so the filename used for your connection is

```
 C:\Users                \Hassan Gillani\Documents\Clinic Management System.accdb;
```

If you try to use File.Exists on this string you get false as result.

Do not split your connection string in the middle of the path

```
   connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
    Data Source=C:\Users\Hassan Gillani\Documents\Clinic Management System.accdb;  
    Persist Security Info = False; ";
```